# How should we declare build variables in VSTS?

Tags: .net, azure-devops, tfsbuild, devops, azure-pipelines

How should we declare build variables in VSTS?

```
$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/SomeFolder
```

or

```
$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\SomeFolder
```

What should we use, forward slash or backward slash?

For example, `$(Build.SourcesDirectory)` is equal to `C:\agent\_work\1\`

According to this we should use this way: `$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\SomeFolder`

But I am not sure. What is correct?

Comment: It generally doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could declare **both** `$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/SomeFolder` and `$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\SomeFolder` build variables in VSTS. They are the same and will auto expand to `C:\agent\_work\1\SomeFolder`

It's not related to build variables in VSTS; it should be more related to the file system. For example, in Windows 10 when you type both `C:\Users\patrick\Pictures\Screenshot` & `C:\Users\patrick\Pictures/Screenshot`. Both of them, you could enter to Screenshot folder.

For more details about build variables in VSTS, please refer to [this official tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/build/variables?view=vsts&tabs=batch).